# FactoryGirl + Rspec association validates has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, has-many

I have standard has_many relation with an object which have validates association. But i don't how to avoid error stack level too deep.

Here my two models

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :employee, :inverse_of => :addresses
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :employee     #inverse of       can use addresses.employee
  has_many :typings
  has_many :types, through: :typings

  validates :addresses, length: { minimum: 1 }
  validates :types, length: { minimum: 1 }


end
```

Here my Factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :address, class: Address do
   address_line 'test'
   name 'Principal'
   city 'test'
   zip_code 'test'
   country 'france'
 end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :employee_with_address_type, class: Employee do |e|
   e.firstname   'Jeremy'
   e.lastname    'Pinhel'
   e.nationality 'France'
   e.promo       '2013'
   e.num_mobile  'Test'
   e.types { |t| [t.association(:type)] }
   after :build do |em|
    em.addresses << FactoryGirl.build(:address)
   end
 end
end
```

Here my model test

```
describe Address do
  context 'valid address' do
  let(:address) {FactoryGirl.build(:address)}
  subject {address}

  #before(:all) do
  #  @employee = FactoryGirl.build(:employee_with_address_type)
  #end

  it 'presence of all attributes' do
     should be_valid
  end
 end
end
```

Someone can help me to understand how to solve this problem ? I try different combination with my factories without success.

EDIT:

```
 class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :addresses, :dependent => :destroy, :inverse_of => :employee     #inverse of       can use addresses.employee
  has_many :typings
  has_many :types, through: :typings

  validates_associated :addresses
  validates_associated :types


 end
```

Comment: Can you post the exception please?

Comment: Here my exception Failure/Error: should be_valid got errors: Employee can't be blank and if add association :employee in my address factory have got stack level too deep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite your factories as follows:

```
     FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :address_with_employee, class: Address do
        address_line 'test'
        name 'Principal'
        city 'test'
        zip_code 'test'
        country 'france'
        association :employee, :factory => :employee_with_address_type
        after :build do |ad|
          ad.employee.addresses << ad
        end
      end
     end

     FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :employee_with_address_type, class: Employee do |e|
        e.firstname   'Jeremy'
        e.lastname    'Pinhel'
        e.nationality 'France'
        e.promo       '2013'
        e.num_mobile  'Test'
        e.types { |t| [t.association(:type)] }
      end
     end
```

What I did was just adding the created address instance directly to its employees addresses. In this after build loop you could of course also create additional addresses with the same employee and add them to the list.

Comment: Thanks, I understand this solution but i still have a failed -> Addresses can't be blank because i have validates on addresses in my Employee model. How i can solve this ?

Comment: I change my constraint on :addresses to valides_associated and now the test is good.